# Output two date languages on the same page without localization

Tags: datetime, language

I'm trying to output a date like this for instance:

```
{{ now|date('l, j-m-Y') }}
```

This outputs the date in my standard language. I need it output on the same page in English too. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to do the translation in the template itself. So if the local is in Dutch but I want to use English:

```
{% set dag = now|date('l' ) %}    
{% set maand = now|date('F' ) %}                                  
{% switch dag %}
    {% case "maandag" %}
       {% set EnDag = 'Monday' %}
    {% case "dinsdag" %}
        {% set EnDag = 'Tuesday' %}
    {% case "woensdag" %}
        {% set EnDag = 'Wednesday' %}
    {% case "donderdag" %}
        {% set EnDag = 'Thursday' %}
    {% case "vrijdag" %}
        {% set EnDag = 'Friday' %}
    {% case "zaterdag" %}
        {% set EnDag = 'Saturday' %}
    {% case "zondag" %}
        {% set EnDag = 'Sunday' %}
{% endswitch %}
 {% switch maand %}
    {% case "januari" %}
       {% set EnMaand = 'January' %}
    {% case "februari" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'February' %}
    {% case "maart" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'March' %}
    {% case "april" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'April' %}
    {% case "mei" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'May' %}
    {% case "juni" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'June' %}
    {% case "juli" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'July' %}
    {% case "augustus" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'August' %}
    {% case "september" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'September' %}
    {% case "oktober" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'October' %}
    {% case "november" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'November' %}
    {% case "december" %}
        {% set EnMaand = 'December' %}
{% endswitch %}                                       
{# output the day #}
{{EnDag}}, {{EnMaand}} {{day.date.format('j, Y')}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Craft/Twig [dateFilter](https://craftcms.com/classreference/etc/templating/twigextensions/CraftTwigExtension#dateFilter-detail) that you're using will currently only translate the string into the current locale the site is set to.

You could probably write a [plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) that added its own Twig Extension that added its own filter... let's call it `|translatedDate` and you could pass in the target locale code as a parameter `|translatedDate('en_us')`.

That filter would do something like:

```
$currentLanguage = craft()->getLanguage();
craft()->setLanguage('en_us');
...
// Do logic similar to Craft's existing date filter
...
craft()->setLanguage($currentLanguage);
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, I started with the plugin, but with my next level php skills ;-) eventually decided to just pickup the local date and translate that in the template (see underneath)